constructibility[geometry] given special tools
It is known that any Euclidean construction, insofar as the given and required elements are points (or circles), may be completed with the compass alone if it can be completed with both the compass and the straightedge together. (Mohr-Mascheroni theorem)
Also known is Poncelet–Steiner theorem, which says: any Euclidean construction, insofar as the given and required elements are points (or lines), if it can be completed with both the compass and the straightedge together, may be completed with the straightedge alone provided that no fewer than one circle with its center exist in the plane.
Here is my question then: If one has a tool that given 2 points on a plane, gives the circle whose diameter is the line segment joining these 2 points, and a tool that given 3 noncollinear points on a plane gives the circle passing through these three, is any Euclidean construction possible? (NO compass, no straight edge)
Obviously if one can draw a circle with a given center and a point on its circumference given the aforementioned two tools all Euclidean constructions are possible due to Mohr-Mascheroni, but can it be shown?

Given two points you can draw the circle whose diameter is the segment joining those points. Now you can’t do anything else. Probably need to add the center of this circle is a known point or a non-collinear point exists, or …..

As pointed out in the comments, you have to assume that you can mark new points on already existing objects and that you can construct intersection of two already existing objects. If we assume this then the answer to your question is positive.
One of the problems on Indian National Math Olympiad 2023 asked the following:

Euclid has a tool called cyclos which allows him to do the following:
Given three non-collinear marked points, draw the circle passing through them.
Given two marked points, draw the circle with them as endpoints of a diameter.
Mark any intersection points of two drawn circles or mark a new point on a drawn circle.
Show that given two marked points, Euclid can draw a circle centered at one of them and passing through the other, using only the cyclos.
Proposed by Rohan Goyal, Anant Mudgal, and Daniel Hu

This gives a positive answer to your question by the Mohr-Mascheroni theorem.
There are several different solutions to the Indian problem on AoPS (one of which is mine). You might want to check them out.
